# Provide properties from groovy script to SOAP request in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

I'm new to Soap UI and I'd like to know what the best approach is to get this task done.

In summary what I wanna do is as follows.

I must read a text file from a groovy script, process that file content and store all the information in a list.

Basically this file will contain a list of banking account numbers as shown below.

- 1020304050607080
- 1020304050607081
- 1020304050607082
- 1020304050607083
- 1020304050607084

After this I have to iterate over the list to get each `account_number` and pass this value to a SOAP request that will consume a web service.

So far I've created a Soap UI project with a test case containing two steps

[image]

`ReadFileAndInvokeWS` step is a groovy script that will perform the functionality I explained earlier:

1. Read a text file line by line and keep information in a list.
2. Iterate over the list and get an `account_number` at a time.
3. Call step #2 `(RegisterAccountWS)` providing `account_number` as an input value.

Step #2 (RegisterAccountWS) is a SOAP request that needs to get access to `account_number`.

[image]

Is there a way to access this value from envelope body in SOAP request?

Or based on your experience, do you suggest a different approach to get the same result?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you're basically talking about is a data driven test.  SoapUI Pro (licensed) let you build such tests out of the box.  However, the free version locks this functionality away.  There are workarounds, suggest searching this site for 'soapui data driven test' as I have seen several workarounds that achieve this.

Comment: @Sandoval0992 
Store the values as properties, and parameterise it in the request XML like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525954/how-can-i-make-requests-in-a-loop-in-soapui-with-different-content/58535311#58535311

Comment: Please look this this thread, something simlar is done. https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-use-value-from-jdbc-response-into-the-json-payload-for-a/m-p/200053#M30245

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i make requests in a loop in soapUI with different content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525954/how-can-i-make-requests-in-a-loop-in-soapui-with-different-content)