# How to check the value of a response based on the values in the request in Soap UI

Tags: soap, soapui, assert

I am a new Soap UI user so the simplest way to convey my ask is with a basic scenario.
At the most basic level I'm sending two numbers and the service returns the addition of those two numbers.

```
request {number1: 5, number2: 10}
response {additiontotal: 15}
```

In my test I want to do the assertion based on what I entered as input
i.e. `assert total == (number1 + number2)`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you using SOAP or REST ? I can show you how to do this in a Groovy script.

Comment: @ou_ryperd I am using SOAP, due to the sensitivity of the case. I can only say that one property in the request must have the same property and the same value in the response

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535311/3355860) answer helps you. Ignore of the CSV and the loop part. You can get the exact response value by using XmlSlurper on the response. You can write an assert statement in the Groovy script to compare that to what was in the property.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You can store the request parameter in Customer properties.. 
2. Refer those values like ${#TestCase#number1} and ${#TestCase@number2} in the request.
3. You can write a groovy to read the value of both properties and sum and assert with response
```

NOTE: you can store properties at TestCase level, TestSuite Level and Project level. The reference should be accordingly change..