# How do i Capturing response value to a excel file in soapui open source

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using free soap-ui version . for basic project (Calculator WSDL). for that i want to save soapui response values to excel, I have written groovy script for that like shown below , am passing multi data in request but in excel its saving last response only , i want to get all response values.
can any one please help me.

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Add#Response") 

log.info holder.getXml()  

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("F:\\Usersdata\\output4.xls"))
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Worksheet 1", 0)

log.info(sheet.isHidden())

xPath1 = "//*:AddResult/text()"     

log.info holder.getNodeValue(xPath1)


Label label = new Label(0, 1, holder.getNodeValue(xPath1)); 
sheet.addCell(label);



workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through the tests, even if it is just one test for now. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535311/3355860) example. Call the WS from inside the loop as well as the part where you write to Excel. In pseudo code:

```
--set up your environment, spreadsheet handle etc.
--for every test case:
    --call web service
    --get result
    --write result
--close off and clean up, save Excel
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please explain in clear i am not good in coding, am using groovy script to read excel data its working , for need to save response xpath value into excel am get only the last response value alone. but i want to save all .

Comment: Yes, read through the example that I linked (it's quite comprehensive) and try what I said. Then, if you can't get it to work, edit your question with the code and the errors you are getting so we can help you fix your code.

Comment: i read the post , am already return another Groovy script to read excel like shown below , i want to save all response to excel. can you please edit above groovy code to iterate and save all response data to excel

Comment: If you want to write each test result to the spreadsheet, you have to loop through the tests and get the results and write them to the sheet inside the loop. I gave you pseudo code and an example of calling SOAP requests in a loop.

Comment: Can you please share the Code , to save each response Xpath value to the Excel sheet .