# How to run multiple request in SOAP UI

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

This is the line

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="" xmlns:oss="">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <oss:SendWorkOrderUpdate>
<WorkOrderId>123</WorkOrderId>
         <WorkOrderAttributes>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <WorkOrderAttribute>
               <Name>Work Order Status</Name>
               <Value>Completed</Value>
          </WorkOrderAttribute>
         </WorkOrderAttributes>
      </oss:SendWorkOrderUpdate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have thousands WorkOrderID to be run. How to trigger multiple request and display the results.

Comment: If you mean you want to iterate over the same test over and over, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535311/3355860

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add a **Groovy Script TestStep** and **put inside a condition** to check whether:

- to make a next round by **testRunner.gotoStepByName()** or
- to stop:

An example:

```
finish = context.expand('${Variables#finish}').toInteger()

if (context.current < finish ) {
    context.current = context.current + 1
    testRunner.gotoStepByName ('IssueFromDB')
}
```

There's a [topic on Smartbear forum for this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/loop-the-test-steps-in-soapui-with-the-help-of-groovy/td-p/124327).